# Load a UIView from a NIB as a subview of another UIView loaded also from a NIB

Tags: iphone, uiview, interface-builder

The idea basically is:
Inside of `myViewController` NIB I have a UIView as a subview, with connections to an `IBOutlet` on `MyViewController` class. I want to load the UIView subview from a NIB also. The subView also has a class associated with it. But the subview is not showing. Here is what I do

on MyViewController.h

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet SubView *subView;     // this outlet is connected to an empty UIView on IB
}
@end
```

on MyViewController.m

```
-(id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        // load the main view 
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewController" owner:self options:nil];
        // load the sub view from another NIB
        self.subView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"subView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

the SubView.h is defined as:

```
@interface SubView : UIView {
}
@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Interface Builder, can't you set the class for the inside-view to be the one you mentioned? Then having a XIB file for it should handle the rest, though I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GianPac - shameless self-promotion, but I did a blog post about this about a month ago.  Feel free to ignore the drop-shadow related code.

http://nathanhjones.com/2011/02/20/creating-reusable-uiviews-with-a-drop-shadow-tutorial/

Also, I (thanks to advice from several people) avoid ever having more than one view controller on my 'view'.  The method I outline above allows you to accomplish this and still use IB to do the layout/outlets.

Comment: That's a nice idea. You do have a memory leak (I commented on your blog), and for this particular question you'd need to override `initWithCoder:` instead of `initWithFrame:` because it's being instantiated in a "parent" nib file.  Also, I _think_ when you're returning a different instance from init, there's no need to call `[super init*]` since we're getting rid of that instance anyways.

Comment: thanks. Still do not know why mine is not loading, but tried yours and worked.

Comment: @daniel - agree that initWithCoder is more appropriate. thanks for the comment on the blog and you were correct, I did have a leak.  I've updated the download file.

Answer (score 4):

What you need to do is set your file owner to be a `UIViewController`, hook up your view to the `view` property of the file owner, save your nib. In your code, load your nib like this:

```
UIViewController* c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Foo" bundle:nil];
SubView* subView = [c view];
```

Should be off to the races.

One final note, is that the type of `subView` should be the same as whatever is defined as the class name in interface builder. If it's a SubView there, then it's safe to declare it as a `SubView*` in code.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something. I have `[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myViewController" owner:self options:nil]; UIViewController *c = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SubView" bundle:nil]; self.subView = (SubView *)[c view];` on IB File's Owner -> UIViewController view -> SubView

Comment: You have to add `subView` as a subview of the containing view you want it to be in. I thought that was fairly self explanatory.

Comment: Thanks you for this, saved me from a sleepless night

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly, but it does seem strange that we need to create a dummy UIViewController that doesn't do anything just to make this work. Do you know why we need to do this?

Comment: It's not a 'dummy'. It's a perfectly good controller that you can add stuff to. For example if you needed to add some code to the controller you could do it in the specific viewController rather than the generic ViewController